# Sort sqlite query in reverse order

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,null,null,ACTIVITY_PRIORITY);
```

This code sorts the query according to `ACTIVITY_PRIORITY`(lower priority is first),
i want higher priority to be first!

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,null,null,ACTIVITY_PRIORITY + " DESC");
```

Check the [database reference guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on android developer website.

Answer (score 2):

By default the order is ASC but you can do this way for DESC.

```
Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,null,null,ACTIVITY_PRIORITY + " DESC");
```